# How do I create a public folder on Dropbox to host HTML files?

Tags: dropbox

I have 2 HTML pages and a CSS page and I want to host it on the Dropbox's public folder.

I have a free plan linked to a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 device.

Unfortunately I failed to create a working public folder.

How can I open a public folder?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you may consider using GitHub to host your page

Create a repository containing your username with ".github.io" appended:

For example, `myusername.github.io`

Now simply upload your files to host it on GitHub

(the site will be visible at `username.github.io`)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this functionality is now deprecated (or at least not available for free users).

> Please note: We have a new, better way to share links to files and folders from anywhere in your Dropbox! Now all you need to do is select Share link from your computer, phone, or tablet. Quickly share anything with friends and colleagues—even if they don’t have Dropbox. Learn more here or go to this article to see how it works.
>
> Because of this new sharing model, Dropbox accounts created after October 4, 2012 no longer have a Public folder. Don't worry! Every account created prior to this date will still have a Public folder. If you'd like to enable a Public folder on a new account, see the instructions below (Creating a Public folder) to learn more.
>
> ...
>
> Dropbox links give you everything you need to share and preview files and folders. However, if you’re just a diehard fan of Public folders, click here to enable one on your account. Currently only Pro and Dropbox for Business users can enable Public folders, so you may have to upgrade first.
> https://www.dropbox.com/help/16

That said, it still doesn't stop you from replicating 'Public Folder' functionality by creating a simple HTML file that contains links to all relevant files that you may want to share via Dropbox ....

Comment: The ability to hotlink it is not available to Pro users either now. Dropbox users used to be able to run web sites using Dropbox, but they took away that feature a few years ago. There was a lot of bandwidth abuse with new account hotlinking copyright files.

Comment: Just to add a source - "As of October 3, 2016 Dropbox Basic (free) users can no longer use public links to render HTML content in a web browser. If you're a Basic user, and you created a website that directly displays HTML content from your Dropbox account, it will no longer render in the browser. The HTML content itself remains safe in Dropbox, and you can share it using any of our other sharing methods. ..."

Same for pro

https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/public-folder